# c# how to check if selected item in listview1 is already in listview2 to prevent duplication?

Tags: c#, validation, listview

how can i validate my listview2 if the row that i selected in listview1 is already in the listview2? i dont understand the listView1.Items.Contains() and ContainKey()

Here's my code to get the selected row in listview1:

```
 private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
            { 
                //how do i condition this selected item? to prevent inserting same items in the listview2
                listView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());//cloning the item to insert in listview2

            }
        }

    }
```

how can i compare the selected row in the listview1 to the items listview2?

Comment: Try this in your for each loop `if(listView2.Items.Contains(item)) { }`

Comment: @NiZa I don't understand why it sill false is my code wrong?
                     if (listView1.Items.Contains(item))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Already existed");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listView1.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
                    }

Comment: You are only looping through your selected items, should that not be `foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)`

Comment: @NiZa is this right? foreach (ListViewItem exist in listView1.Items) i put breakpoints on it and it didnt enter inside the foreach.

Comment: If you have a count that is bigger than 0, you should get in it.

Comment: @RhenzoPacho why you not just copy only value of an item? I see you copy a `ListViewItem`. This is not recommended.

Comment: @NiZa i did the `foreach (ListViewItem exist in listView2.Items)` inside the first foreach statement and the second foreach didnt loop maybe because my listview2 is empty?

Comment: @sakura what should i use to pick the selected row and copy it another listview? i dont get it.

Comment: No, just pick data, dont pick control.

Comment: @Sakura do you mean i should use `listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]].Text;`?

Comment: @RhenzoPacho see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `listView1`'s items is list of string, you can use

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You don't need to check:  if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
    {
        bool isExist = false;
        foreach (ListViewItem item2 in listView2.Items)
        {
            if (item2.Text == item.Text) // Compare Text
            //if (item2.ImageKey == item.ImageKey) // Compare Key. If you don't use key then ignore this line
            {
                isExist = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isExist) listView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
    }
}
```

Comment: this will works but my visualstudio says that `(!listView2.Items.Contains(item))` the item cannot convert object to System.WIndows.Forms.ListViewItem and `listView2.Items.Add(item);` cannot conver object to string

Comment: i already did that earlier before ipost it here. the problem there is it keeps giving true value and keep adding even the list is already listed.

Comment: Pls check again, I just modify it.

Comment: oooh its working now, thank you!!! ill just figure out how this work. i really dont know what im doin right now, im still not sleeping for 2 days until now. thank you again.

Comment: @RhenzoPacho your code compare 2 objects, not 2 strings, that why it don't work.

Comment: So it is really important to convert those 2 object to string then compare. Thanks again.

Comment: Not convert to string, but point to a string property inside the object.

Comment: Oh i get it now, i hope i could get some sleep now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
   {
       foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
       { 
          if(!listView2.Items.Contains(item)) //verify text and value. if don't contain add
              listView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());

      }
   }

}
```